# Command to find EC2 instance boot time

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

How we can calculate the response of time (i.e. from the time instance is started and till it has completely boot) of an instance through commands?

Answer (score 1):

This information is in /var/log/messages

Check this post out: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=100535